# System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow: Why are the standard block types implemented with List rather than Queue?

Tags: .net, queue, generic-list, tpl-dataflow

[image]

The debug session shown is from the sample program provided on [How to: Implement a Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern).

In System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, why are the standard block types such as BufferBlock implemented with a List rather than a Queue? Most of the dataflow blocks (especially `BufferBlock<T>`) are intended to be used as FIFO, but popping the head of a list is `O(n)` rather than `O(1)` for Queue. Mainly I'm curious if anyone has any insight into a possible rationale for this design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never make any conclusions based on debugging session, examine the source first.

Consider the class information for [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Blocks/BufferBlock.cs)

```
public IEnumerable<T> Queue { get { return _sourceDebuggingInformation.OutputQueue; } }
```

As you can see, the `Queue` property here coming from a **debugging information** field.

Let's take a look for that [class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/SourceCore.cs):

```
internal IEnumerable<TOutput> OutputQueue { get { return _source._messages.ToList(); } }
```

Again, as you can see, this is **not** list-based queue, it's the queue being transformed to list for **debugging**.

Finally, let's see what type has the `_messages` field. It's [`SingleProducerSingleConsumerQueue<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ProducerConsumerQueues.cs,99), which works exactly how it should.

Comment: Interesting. First I've ever heard that a debugger could be coerced into displaying a different type than the underlying variable. Too much to learn and too little time :/

Comment: It's not coersed, it's a calculated property, you can do it yourself :) If you want to understand the internals of a class, you should examine non-public fields in debugger.